# how to add if else condtion in hibernate configuration file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working in spring hibernate project where I am connecting to multiple database. These database details are loaded in a properties file and is imported into hibernate.xml file. Each key was mapped as below.

dbName= dbHost

**Mapping as below :**

```
<bean id="dbId" parent="abstractDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="${dbName}" />
</bean>
```

But now i need to include a condition such that the property key to be mapped to multiple values like below

E.g.  dbName= statusFlag,dbHost,dbBackupHostName

I need to modify the hibernate configuration file such that using the keyName, corresponding values should be retrieved and splitted with comma separated. 
Then I need to check for the statusFlag. If it is true, then i should set the dbValue to 'dbHost', else if the flag is false, it should be set to 'dbBackupHostName'.

Please help me how to implement this condition check in hibernate configuration file.

Also please let me know if this approach is fine to proceed or am i making it too difficult to implement?
Waiting for some valueable answers..

~~~Suriya

Comment: Which spring version are you using ?

Comment: @11thdimension -  I am using spring 3.0.5 version

Comment: So back up a step.  You need to have three different database names for one bean?

Comment: @Makoto - no. I need to check for the flag status, then set the bean to main db or backup db

Answer (score 0):

To use complex logic in bean wiring and creation in spring you can use [Java Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/)

It should work for Spring 3. Sample pseudo code is below.

```
@Configuration
public class MyCustomConfig {
    @Value
    String statusFlag;
    @Value
    String dbHost;
    @Value
    String dbBackupHostName;

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource datasource () {
        BasicDataSource datasource = new BasicDataSource();
        //Do some custom processing to create datasource
        ...
        return datasource;//return after creation
    }
}
```

Use [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to load properties as [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) is not available in 3.0.5.

If you can change the spring version to **3.1** which shouldn't make much difference then you can use [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) along with [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).
If the logic is not too complex and you can separate set of properties that have to be active at a time. (Local db, Dev db, Prod db, Custom etc.) Then you can try using [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html).

[@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotated bean is created only if that profile is active. A profile can be activated by setting [spring.profiles.active](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME).

So to activate the Dev profile we can set in the properties files

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
//activating 2 profiles
spring.profiles.active=dev,mvc
```

Below is the sample pseudo code.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("bootstrap.properties")//set spring.profiles.active in it
public class MyCustomConfig {
    @Profile("profile1")
    public BasicDataSource datasource1 () {
        //config using ${profile1.dbName} etc
        ...
    }

    @Profile("profile2")
    public BasicDataSource datasource2 () {
        //config using ${profile2.dbName} etc
        ...
    }

    @Profile("profile3")
    public BasicDataSource datasource3 () {
        //config using ${profile3.dbName} etc
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try the same and update if that works